# Duda con async/await

Tags: javascript

Conozco el comportamiento (casi todo) de las keyword async / await;
Y justo ayer estaba jugando con unas funciones para ver cómo se comportaba
y me topé con algo que me dejó un poco confundido.

¿Por qué funciona de esta manera el poner "await" a la function find?

Aquí les dejo el código de prueba y los logs para que se entienda lo que digo.

```js
!async function() {
  let arrayNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  let numbersToFind = [7, 4, 5];
  let result =  arrayNumbers.filter(async e => {
    console.log('inside filter')
    let found = await numbersToFind.find( a => {
      return a === e; 
    });
    console.log('down found');
    if(found) {
      console.log(found);
      console.log('dentro de encontrado')
      return e;
    }
  });
  console.log('outside functions');
  console.log(result);
}();
```

[image: those are the logs]

Comment: Hey, you are at [es.so]. Please translate your question to spanish, otherwise it will be closed. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada. Aprovecho de invitarte a leer [ask] y realizar el [tour]. Saludos

Comment: Hola debes mejorar tu pregunta: la verdad veo que la funcion se ejecuta puedes indicar que es lo que esperas como resultado ???

Comment: Una disculpa por que no la deje muy clara, mi duda es por el comportamiento que tiene la funcion al agregar el "await" a una function como el find(), veo que ejecuta todas las iteraciones del metodo, pero luego continua el flujo y comienzan a aparecer los logs fuera de las funciones, como si se comportara de forma asyncronica.

Answer (score 4):

No tengo muy claro qué es lo que te extraña del comportamiento, así que vamos a analizarlo paso a paso:

```
1 !async function() {
```

Declaras una función anónima que devolverá una promesa

```
2     let arrayNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
3     let numbersToFind = [7, 4, 5];
```

Vale, tenemos dos arrays normales con números...

```
4     let result =  arrayNumbers.filter(async e => {
```

Uh-oh, primera cosa rara: el método filter permite filtrar los elementos de un array. Para hacerlo usa la función que le pasas como parámetro y la llama para cada elemento del array. Si la función devuelve *verdadero*, se queda con el elemento y si no lo descarta. ¿Por qué  he puesto *verdadero* en cursiva? Bueno, porque para Javascript cualquier valor que no sea `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `0` o una cadena vacía (`''`) se puede interpretar como verdadero:

```js
console.log("un objeto es verdadero?", !!{});
```

Al declararse la función que filtra como asíncrona, está devolviendo un objeto de la clase `Promise`, por lo tanto siempre será procesado como `verdadero`... es decir, que no estamos filtrando nada, como veremos más adelante.

```
5         console.log('inside filter')
```

En cada iteración del filtro, escribimos un texto, nada especial aquí... pero es bueno resaltar que claramente se ve que las promesas se intentan cumplir inmediatamente y en este caso se consigue porque no hay que esperar nada.

```
6         let found = await numbersToFind.find( a => {
7             return a === e; 
8         });
```

Aquí usar `await` no aporta nada, es una función no asíncrona, pero provoca que la resolución se quede "en espera", provocando que se muestren otros logs antes.

```js
let asyncFn = async () => {
  let array= [1,2,3,4];
  let found = await array.find(e=> e===3);
  console.log('1',found);
};

let asyncFn2 = async () => {
  let array= [1,2,3,4];
  let found = array.find(e=> e===3);
  console.log('2',found);
};

asyncFn()
asyncFn2()
```

```
9         console.log('down found');
10        if(found) {
11            console.log(found);
12            console.log('dentro de encontrado')
13            return e;
14        }
15    });
16    console.log('outside functions');
17    console.log(result);
18}();
```

El resto de código no tiene nada de especial, muestra los datos que se esperaban.

Ahora imaginemos que tenemos que filtrar valores de un array y el resultado depende de una llamada AJAX, por ejemplo. ¿Cómo podríamos hacerlo? Pues en dos pasos:

```js
async function esPar(n) {
  return n%2 ===0;
}
//Simplemente probamos que funciona
esPar(3).then(resultado => {
  console.log('El número 3 es par?', resultado);
});

let array = [1,2,3,4];

//guardamos el resultado de aplicar la función esPar a cada elemento
let resultadosP = array.map(esPar);
console.log('Promesas!', resultadosP.toString());

Promise.all(resultadosP).then(resultados => {
//Nos quedamos con los elementos donde esPar devolvió "true"
  let filtrados = array.filter((elem,indice) => {
     return resultados[indice];
  });
  
  console.log(filtrados);
});
```